# Master ipv4 CIDR configuration for private cluster in GCP

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, rfc

I'm trying to create a private cluster in GCP as per the steps mentioned here:
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters

As per this, the ipv4 address for the master node is set to 172.16.0.32/28.
I have also seen that the same CIDR blocks are used in many other examples as well.
Is there a restriction that only this particular CIDR block should be used for master when configuring a GKE private cluster?
If yes, then, can my VPC/subnets have a different range of CIDR , for ex, 10.1.0.0/16? 
As in, can the master node reside in one subnet and the nodes in a different subnet?

If there is no restriction on the master ipv4 address range, then can I use any RFC1918 range for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only restrictions, based on [1] public documentation, are:

> **Restrictions**
>
> Private clusters have the following restrictions:
>
> - ...
> - You cannot use a cluster master, node, Pod, or Service IP range that overlaps with 172.17.0.0/16.
> - ...
>
> **Limitations**
>
> Private clusters have the following limitations:
>
> - Each private cluster you create uses a unique VPC Network Peering.
> - Each VPC network can peer with up to 25 other VPC networks.
> - The size of the RFC 1918 block for the cluster master must be /28.
> - While GKE can detect overlap with the cluster master address block, it
>   cannot detect overlap within a shared VPC network.

So basically you can use any private ip range that does not violates any of the rules stated before.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#limitations